# Issues with getting css and js files from index.html source code in Vue Project, try to implement assets folder

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

The issue is that the source code cannot recognize or GET the ressources, both JS and css files. I have tried many chnages in relative path, within my index.html file, additionally I have even tried to put the assets folder in the same directory as the index.html file, which is the main vue project file. This may be vague, but I have tried may fixes, and it hasn't been resolved.

Additionally, when in console as shown, it uses to show a MIME error for the css, as well as a "ressource not found" error for the js, however changing the href--> src for the css as well as specifyign 'type="text/js"' resolved console errors.

However, they are still not found when the links are pressed in the page source via chrome. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B2y9.png)

```html
<!-- Animate.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="assets/css/animate.css">
    <!-- Icomoon Icon Fonts-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="assets/css/icomoon.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="assets/css/bootstrap.css">

    <!-- Magnific Popup -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="assets/css/magnific-popup.css">

    <!-- Owl Carousel  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="assets/css/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="assets/css/owl.theme.default.min.css">

    <!-- Theme style  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="assets/css/style.css">

    <!-- Modernizr JS -->
    <script type="text/js" src="assets/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FOR IE9 below -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        
        
        
        
        
        
        <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/js" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Easing -->
    <script type="text/js" src="assets/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script type="text/js" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Waypoints -->
    <script type="text/js" src="assets/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Carousel -->
    <script type="text/js" src="assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <!-- countTo -->
    <script type="text/js" src="assets/js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
    <!-- Magnific Popup -->
    <script type="text/js" src="assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/js" src="assets/js/magnific-popup-options.js"></script>
    <!-- Main -->
    <script type="text/js" src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B2Gh.png)

Comment: `script type="text/js"` ... try `script type="application/javascript"` or removing type altogether as it is not required in modern browsers - similarly with stylesheets, don't use type attribute - not saying this will fix your problem, but `text/js` has NEVER been a valid type for javascript - and there have been many valid types

Comment: what it looks like is your http server is messing things up - of course, we can't see if your assets/js and assets/css folders actually contain the files you want

Comment: Where did you get the `text/js` thing?

Comment: @Bravo How would I reference them in order for them to see that the files are actually contained in those directories?

Comment: I don't know, are you using vue-cli? If so read the [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/)